# how do i perform a summary for distinct values in msql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have this table coming from mysql which i output using the following code,

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE subunit='$subunit' and part='$part' and session='$session' and class ='$class' order by names asc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ 
   echo strtoupper("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[2]</td><td>$data[3]</td><td>$data[4]</td><td>$data[5]</td><td>$data[6]</td><td>$data[7]</td></tr>"); 
   }
 ?>

NAMES   ID  COURSES LETTER  WEIGHT  UNIT    SUBUNIT SESSION PART    CLASS
john    2012/185301 GSP111  F   0   ARTIST  UNN 2012/2013   FIRST   100
john    2012/185301 HIS121  D   4   ARTIST  UNN 2012/2013   FIRST   100
john    2012/185301 PHL101  D   4   ARTIST  UNN 2012/2013   FIRST   100
jude    2011/176363 TRM201  C   6   ARTIST  UNE 2012/2013   FIRST   200
jude    2011/176363 ACH211  D   4   ARTIST  UNE 2012/2013   FIRST   200
mary    2011/176363 ACH231  B   12  ARTIST  UNE 2012/2013   FIRST   200
```

pls how do i make it to outut the following table with the weight coming immediately after every distinct row ends?

```
NAMES   ID  COURSES LETTER  WEIGHT  UNIT    SUBUNIT SESSION PART    CLASS
john    2012/185301 GSP111  F   0   ARTIST  UNN 2012/2013   FIRST   100
john    2012/185301 HIS121  D   4   ARTIST  UNN 2012/2013   FIRST   100
john    2012/185301 PHL101  D   4   ARTIST  UNN 2012/2013   FIRST   100
total weight = 8                                    
jude    2011/176363 TRM201  C   6   ARTIST  UNE 2012/2013   FIRST   200
jude    2011/176363 ACH211  D   4   ARTIST  UNE 2012/2013   FIRST   200
total weight = 10                   ARTIST  UNE 2012/2013   FIRST   200
mary    2011/176363 ACH231  B   12                  
total weight = 12
```

Comment: The most sensible way to achieve this would be using more than one query, because the data itself is no longer tabular (although the effect you want can still be achieved quite easily with HTML tables and `colspan`) - you can easily get the respective totals using `SELECT name, SUM(weight) FROM ... GROUP BY name`, but it will require additional logic processing in PHP to convert this into the display format you want.

Answer (score 1):

You really cannot do this directly in SQL.  In SQL all the columns are defined by the query, so they are the same for every row. You are asking for two different types of columns.

There are hacks to work around this.  One would be to concatenate all the values in the row so the table is really just a table of strings.  Another would be to blank out all the other columns and put the total weight in an additional column.

However, in this case, the best solution is to do the work at the application layer.  Loop through the results and add new rows to your output as you see fit.